# javascript and html traffic light not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

So the red traffic light shows up and then when the next light button is pressed the light doesn't change and I can't for the life of me figure out why. I would appreciate any help. Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>

    <img id="thestartlight" src="file:\\\C:\Users\Sony\Desktop\Amul's USB\IT\it test\traffic-light-red.jpg">

    <button type="button" onclick="nextLightClick()">Next Light</button>

    <script>
      var list = [
        "file:\\\C:\Users\Sony\Desktop\Amul's USB\IT\it test\traffic-light-red.jpg.html"
        "file:\\\C:\Users\Sony\Desktop\Amul's USB\IT\it test\traffic-light-amber.jpg",
        "file:\\\C:\Users\Sony\Desktop\Amul's USB\IT\it test\traffic-light-green.jpg",
        "file:\\\C:\Users\Sony\Desktop\Amul's USB\IT\it test\traffic-light-red.jpg"
      ];

      var index = 0;
      var lightsLen = lights.length;

      function nextLightClick() {
        index++;

        if (index == lightsLen) 
          index = 0;

        var image = document.getElementById('thestartlight');
        image.src = lights[index];
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: spelling. `var list` != `lights`

Comment: do you mean `list.length` ? instead of `lights.length` or it's always 0, like ben just said :)

Comment: Also you have a syntax error, look at your console for errors

Comment: where you define var lights in above code ?

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 problems.

1) it's `list` have to be `lights`

2) better put images to `images/lights/` folder in relative to Your code folder.

3) html file cannot be shown in image tag

Here is the fix:

```
var lights = [ 
   "images/lights/amber.jpg", 
   "images/lights/green.jpg", 
   "images/lights/red.jpg"
]; 
var index = 0; 
var lightsLen = lights.length;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a typo..

```
 var list = [ ...
```

should be

```
 var lights [ ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You named your array `list`, but you are seeking the images from `lights`.

You also need to remove the `.html` file from the array.

```js
var image = document.getElementById('thestartlight');


var lights = [
"http://archive.nassaucountyny.gov/agencies/TPVA/Images/RedLight-2_145x193.jpg",
"http://www.clker.com/cliparts/2/1/1/6/N/W/amber-traffic-light.svg",
"http://www.clker.com/cliparts/6/e/9/d/11949849761176136192traffic_light_green_dan__01.svg"
];

var index = 0;
var lightsLen = lights.length;

function nextLightClick() {
   index++;

  if (index == lightsLen){ 
      index = 0;
  }

  image.src = lights[index];
}
```

```css
img {width:50px;}
```

```html
<img id="thestartlight" src="http://archive.nassaucountyny.gov/agencies/TPVA/Images/RedLight-2_145x193.jpg">

<button type="button" onclick="nextLightClick()">Next Light</button>
```